# Why does Android Studio say "Test events were not received"?

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, junit, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to unit test in my android application, and this is the simple test tutorial what i'm doing.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ServerListManagerTest extends AndroidTestCase{

   @Test
   public void testTrueIsTrue() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

The directory is like this, `src\main\androidTest\java\some packages\ServerListManagerTest.java`

I tried changing directory of this, and also build configuration.
but android studio still doesn't recognize my unit test though build was successful.

This is my build.gradle in app,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.kaist.se.pmpapp"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 21
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }

buildTypes {
       release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
      }
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/androidTest/java'] } } }



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
  }
```

What's wrong in my code????

Comment: In my case, I just scrolled down the message window and found actually error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I assume you're using Android Studio version 1.2, the latest at this time.

I don't think anything is wrong with your code.  According to [Jason Atwood's post](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/), the problem seems related to gradle caching the previous results and not running it again. If you look at the "Gradle console", you'll see everything say "UP-TO-DATE".  However, his suggestion of adding the "--rerun-tasks" option to the script parameters was not sufficient for me.

In **addition** to "--rerun-tasks", I had to turn off the in-process build and force it to call the external `gradlew` tool.  To do this, go to...

```
File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler
```

Then un-check the "Use in-process build" option.  Hopefully a future release of Android Studio will fix this and we can re-enable that option.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now I can see the message 'No tests found for given includes', though my test code is same above.

Comment: At least it's a different problem so we're making progress.  I believe your test is on the wrong directory.  I have mine in `src/test/java/...` (i.e. parallel to _main_).  `src/androidTest/java` is for tests run on the device itself.

Comment: In the report the unit tests were successful but AS said test events were not received. I just disabled "Use in-process build" according to your advice, and now I see the result in AS. I freaking hate this kind of things in tools. Why can't they just work as expected out of the box, without user's spending hours for unknown errors and then finally searching the web for a fix.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, it works, but I have a strange issue. In the report, the unit tests seems to have run once. But in AS, there are "Gradle Test Executor 1" and "Gradle Test Executor 2" running the same tests twice each. This is not a serious problem for me, but can I fix this?

Comment: @SinJeong-hun I just tried this on Android Studio 1.2.2, it is indeed only the "in-process build" option that makes the difference. The `--rerun-tasks` switch didn't change anything. I feel your pain, instead of doing the actual work I'm forced to deal with this stuff.

Comment: @Malcolm this is weird, I'm on AS 1.2.2 as well and disabling "in-process build" didn't change anything for me, but adding "--rerun-tasks" did the trick.

Comment: After spending 4 hours fighting this with Android Studio 1.2.2 on my Mac, disabling in-process build fixed the issue.

Comment: FIxed the issue, but now my tests seem to be running twice. Better than none at all, I suppose

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. Wasted a days development finding out what the problem was. Obviously productivity belongs in other languages and environments.

Comment: Hey guys where is this option in the current Android Studio?

Answer (score 68):

Sometimes you might have simple a compiler issue and end up with this message. This happened to me.. The compiler issue was not pointed out directly had to scroll down on the stack trace to find what is the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same issue `Test events were not received` , I checked the  function I wrote and found that there is a **compiler error.**

My solution is **`check the files/functions you are testing`** there may be compiler errors

this may help some one with same problem.

Comment: Thanks, exactly my case. I would add that links compilation errors were actually presented in the logs above.

Comment: Thanks for this! In my case, it was a compiler error somewhere else in that module's test code, unrelated to the test I was trying to run.

Comment: Generally the log console of the running test shows what's wrong. In my case there was also a compiler error but I didn't scroll until the end of the log console... that's a learnt lesson for me. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

On my side I fixed the issue by using:

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`

instead of

`import org.junit.Test`

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple Flavours, you may have selected another flavour, not the one with your tests. E.g. if you have `prod` and `debug` flavour and your tests are in `debug`, you may have switched to `prod` one and then you'll get the same error. Selecting the `debug` flavour will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (AS Chipmunk), I started receiving this error after trying to modify the run configurations for the tests (to stop code coverage from showing the Hilt generated classes).

What I did was delete the `.idea` folder and after restarting Android Studio tests were working once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build the project and run tests again. In my case I had a bug in the code and therefore the tests did not run either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, apart from fixing compiling issues, none of the answers worked. However, invalidating Android Studio's cache did the trick.

1. Go to `File`
2. Press `Invalidate Caches...`
3. Click on `Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that one of the test methods I had written was missing `public` from the method declaration. Like

```java
@Test
void testSomething() {
   //
}
```

as opposed to

```java
@Test
public void testSomething() {
}
```

Interestingly even though I was trying to debug some other properly defined method in the same class, the framework would not find any of the tests in the class.

So it's not just the syntax errors, but the semantic issues wrt the unit test framework also throw everything off.

Answer (score 0):

In My case the solution was to go to
androidStudio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle
and then, change Gradle JDK (From 15 to 13)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Do double check if you are in gradle offline mode. A stupid but pretty common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue, but for future google searchers and perhaps interested parties that could work around this, it is worth mentioning that if you are using one of the more popular walk-throughs to set up JaCoCo + Robolectric + Espresso - https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa . Please add below this:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jacoco.includeNoLocationClasses = true
    jacoco.excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar message with instrumented tests. Turned out, you have to run `connectedAndroidTest` for them to be run.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when some of the unit test cases fail. Try to run

```
./gradlew clean testDebugUnitTest
```

to get the failing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to crop up in different ways over the years. Here is what fixed it for me in 2023 with Studio 2022.2.1 Patch 2.

Tests in module projects were not running and "Tests not recieved" error.  Added this to the module's gradle to fix:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.foo.bar"
    testOptions {
         unitTests {
            all {
                 it.enabled = true
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by appending the following plugin declaration to my module's build.gradle file's existing plugins:

```
plugins {
    ...
    ...
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the mockito library that I imported into my project, after deleting it it worked again, see if there is no new libraries that you imported, delete them just to test that the problem comes from a newly added lib.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I synced **old dependency** from a tutorial, So I copied the `correct dependency` from the `official site`.