# Junit5 Testing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I'm trying to conduct a unit test on a function that removes special characters from a string.

This is the method I'm trying to test:

```
public String sanitize(String string) {

    String regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]";
    return string.replaceAll(regex, "");
}
```

This is part of a class called AddTeam.  I have a test class named AddTeamTest where I'm trying to run a simple test:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class AddTeamTest {

    @Test
    public void sanitize() {

        AddTeam team = new AddTeam();

        String input1 = "abc123";
        String expected1 = "abc123";
        assertEquals(expected1, team.sanitize(input1));
    }
}
```

Any time I try to run the test, I get an error from Android Studio that says Test Events were not received.  I've tried rebuilding the project and resyncing the gradle file, but it doesn't seem to help.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394256/why-does-android-studio-say-test-events-were-not-received? It would be helpful to know what you tried so far.

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue to the line AddTeam team = new AddTeam();  This is causing the issue with the test consistently.  I've double checked dependencies, but I'm new to unit testing, and I'm not really 100% sure what all I need.

Comment: You need to import your AddTeam class! Your Test class doesn't know what that object is. Something like import main.StackOverflowQuestions.AddTeam; Whatever your project set up structure is.

Comment: That may well have resolved the issue, but I figured out another way around it for this situation.  Because I was testing data validation and sanitation methods, I created a different class (I probably should have done that in the first place).  Since the created class didn't have any activities, it could run the tests successfully. I believe this has something to do with needing Android-specific resources for the Activity class that I was trying to reference, and my AVM didn't satisfy it.